# Xcode creating a Realm target by itself

Tags: xcode, realm, target

This is what it shows:

[image]

And when I click Manage Schemes I get this: 
[image]

This is how it added the schemes:
[image]

however I do not have Realm in my pods or my project:
[image]

I used to at some point, but got rid of it. Also at some point I had installed Realm package with Alcatraz, but I also deleted that. I am using Swiftlint but I guess they are not related. So there should no reason for my scheme to automatically change to Realm randomly. (Usually when I restart Xcode or clean build)

What is this and how do I get rid of it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a CocoaPods or Xcode cacheing issue to me. Try this:

```
pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
pod install --verbose
```

You can also try deleting derived data and cleaning the build folder in Xcode; a number of our users have reported that this solved their CocoaPods issues. To clean the build folder, hold down the ‘Option’ key while opening the ‘Product’ menu, then choose ‘Clean Build Folder…’. You can also type “Clean” into the Xcode help search menu and select the ‘Clean Build Folder…’ menu item when it shows up in the search results.